# NgClass not adding all specified classes on true

Tags: angular

I am using `ngClass` directive on the following html:

```
<i [ngClass]="{'fa fa-check': value, 'fa fa-cross':!value}"></i>
```

Which works perfectly fine when `value == false` - it adds `fa fa-cross` to the icon. However, when `value == true`, it only adds `fa-check` to the element.

See the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/L6y83ZJ6fehoIRKOqqqK?p=preview).

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will work when you change it to this:

```
<i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-check': value, 'fa-cross':!value}"></i>
```

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OFNAtZSip84z6ZfCbVAU?p=preview). I've also change `fa-cross` to `fa-times`, so we can see the change live.

Comment: @micronyks added plnkr

Comment: @micronyks it works. Thanks, it should be fa-times from the beginning

Comment: good now. without plunker it was incomplete answer. you can change class name in your answer. that will help others.

Answer (score 3):

That's how ngClass works. It toggles the classes.

Your initial value for your condition is false, therefore it adds `fa fa-cross`. When the condition changes to true both classes are removed and `fa-check` is added.

Here's a really good [explanation of how ngClass works](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5763#issuecomment-166114033). Thanks to @galpalk for amazing answer.

I suggest you to do what @uksz answered. That's the correct answer.

Comment: So, it is more like a classToggle?

Comment: Yes, you could say so. See this [piece of code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/directives/ng_class.ts#L173), it's called `toggleClass` for a reason.

Comment: Some things get worse on newer versions. I am not sure why this change was made, but ngClass was working much better and much more expected in Angular 1.*. Perhaps we get used to this, perhaps not. We will see.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to setting the class-logic in your template, you may implement a getter in your component:

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES,NgClass} from 'angular2/common';


@Component({
  selector: 'main-view',
  template: `<h1> Main View </h1>
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="value">
<i [ngClass]="checkboxClass"></i>
        `,
  directives:[FORM_DIRECTIVES,NgClass]
})

export class MainViewComponent{

  constructor(){
        this.value = false;
  }

  public get checkboxClass(): string {
    return this.value ? 'fa fa-check' : 'fa fa-times';
  }

}
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/I5hwjRFelIQP8KepJBgI?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

[NgClass](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgClass-directive.html)

> Object - each key corresponds to a CSS class name while values are
>   interpreted as expressions evaluating to Boolean. If a given
>   expression evaluates to true a corresponding CSS class is added -
>   **otherwise it is removed**.

emphasis mine.

It looks like it explicitly removes the classes that are evaluated to false. So although it is added in the true case, it is also removed for the false case. Interestingly it appears to do the add/removing class in order of the key, so if you do your not case first, it removes `fa` and then adds it again for your true case.

```
"{'fa fa-cross':!value,'fa fa-check': value}"
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/V9l9Gv2dnyZJA1ovubni?p=preview

I believe uksz solution is the correct way, that is, to explicitly add the class to the tag since it is there for both cases.